# Build Qt for VS and GCC

Tags: visual-studio, qt, gcc, build, configure

I need to build QT for Visual Studio and MinGW. I want to obtain folder structure like this:

```
Qt
  /minGW
    /bin
    /lib
 /vs2008
    /bin
    /lib
 /include
 /src
 /... other in Qt archive
```

Is it possible using configure.exe, and how?

Beforehand thankfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to run `configure.exe` twice; once for VS and once or minGW. You'll need to specify different installation directories each time as well.

Comment: How to specify install directory?

Comment: I read about `-prefix`, but it seems like it is only in old versions of qmake.